# Convert a big integer to a full string in PHP

Tags: php, casting, integer, type-conversion

I've been searching for a while now, but what I can find is not what I search for. I need to convert an integer value, that may be *very huge*, to a string. Sounds easy: `"$var"`? No, because this can lead to the `E+` representation of the number.

```
<?php

$var = 10000000000000000000000000;
echo $var."\n";
echo "'$var'\n";
echo (string) $var."\n";
echo strval($var);

?>
```

```
1.0E+25
'1.0E+25'
1.0E+25
1.0E+25
```

How can I make the output be `10000000000000000000000000` instead?

Comment: Please note that your "very huge integer" is not represented in your computer as an integer, as it exceeds both 32bit and 64bit bounds.

Comment: $var = '10000000000000000000000000';

Comment: You cannot do this with a native int value. It will have to be stored as a string. If you're doing math operations on this number, you'll have to use the [bcmath](http://php.net/bcmath) library.

Comment: Note that if you are decoding large integers from JSON, you can use `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` as the 4th argument to `json_decode`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not stored as an integer by PHP, but a float, this is why you end up with 1.0E+25 instead of 10000000000000000000000000.

It's sadly not possible to use that as an integer value in PHP, as PHP cannot save an integer of that size. If this comes from database then it will be a string and you can do with it whatever you want. If you store it elsewhere then store it as a string.

Your alternative is to store it as a float and take that into account at all times, though that requires additional conversions and handling in places.

It's also been suggested to use [GNU Multiple Precision](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), but that's not enabled in PHP by default.

```
$int=gmp_init("10000000000000000000000000");
$string=gmp_strval($int);
echo $string;
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest GMP. Don't use a float - the precision at that large of a number isn't reliable.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**
Found the next post:

```
// strval() will lose digits around pow(2,45);
echo pow(2,50); // 1.1258999068426E+015
echo (string)pow(2,50); // 1.1258999068426E+015
echo strval(pow(2,50)); // 1.1258999068426E+015

// full conversion
printf('%0.0f',pow(2,50)); // 112589906846624
echo sprintf('%0.0f',pow(2,50)); // 112589906846624
```

Use `printf` or `sprintf`.

Comment: I submit it in mistake before adding the second part of the answer

Comment: Floats aren't reliable at this size. `echo sprintf("%0.0f", 10000000000000000000000000);` on my system outputs `10000000000000000905969664`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing this problem when getting facebook id and find it in MySQL.
And after half hour, i found this work perfectly!
Insert this line to your php script:

```
ini_set('precision',30);
```

From: https://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/125907-solved-convert-big-number-to-string/#entry651084

Comment: After spending Whole day i found this tip. it save my life. Thanks Duo.

Answer (score 2):

The integer number you like to express:

```
$var = 10000000000000000000000000;
```

is not available on your system. It's too large and therefore PHP converts it into a float which will change the number (32 bit system example):

```
       10000000000000000905969664
```

Common limits are:

```
 yours :  10 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
 32 bit:                       2 147 483 648
 64 bit:           9 223 372 036 854 775 808
```

The change of the value is called floating point precision, the [PHP manual about integers](http://php.net/integer) will tell you about the integer limit and [the floats page about floating point precision](http://php.net/float) (see the big red warning). Depending on which system you are, you can compile PHP with the ranges your application needs or you must use another datatype, for example with [the gmp library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) which is able to pick strings as integer numbers and handle them.

The following example shows just output, but you can do multiplications etc.:

```
$r = gmp_init('10000000000000000000000000');
echo gmp_strval($r);
```

Hope this is helpful.