# php array phone number fields stored as int

Tags: php, arrays, phone-number

I had a MySQL table with some user data, which I needed to correct and migrate to a new MySQL table.  I exported the table using "Export to PHP Array plugin for PHPMyAdmin" from "Geoffray Warnants" and it returned a (PHP) array.

One of the fields contains a telephone number.  Now some of the entries have been exported as string.  However, some of the entries have the telephone number represented as an integer. When I try to read the number, it returns something like:

```
4.36991052022E+12
```

when it should be:

```
4369910520219
```

I suppose the integer value is too big, so that must be the problem. (that's the reason for the E+12)
I have close to 300 entries and there is no way I can start writing quotes in front and end of the number manually, since I also have a fax field.

Most recently, I tried (with help of demo sublime text 2) to cast the number by writing (string) in front of it - it doesn't work.

I'm kind of helpless now and ask for your help. What can I do?

Comment: Wow, 13-digit phone number? Where are you from?

Comment: @TomášZato Indian mobile no are mostly 10 digit + 2 digit country code + 0 = 13 digit look fine to me.

Comment: well the 43 can also be written as 0043 or +43 is the direct dialing for Austria, where i currently live. and 699 is the identifier for the carrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't have the time to get trough the "complicated" process of installing the GMP library, I decided to make it old-skool and just put double quotes ("") in front of every phone number value no matter if is was a string or a "big integer" and remove (single) quotes from the final string.
Thanks to Sublime Text 2!

So i had:

```
array(..., 'phone'=>' 43 664 1000383', ...);
```

and

```
array(..., 'phone'=>4369910520219, ...);
```

> Search for and Find All **'phone'=>** and add afterwards **"**
>   Then search for (in my case) **,'fax'=>** and add beforehand **"**
>   The for every string

```
preg_replace("/\'/i", "", $user["phone"]);
```

Thanks though for the library. I might actually use it someday. ;)

Greetings,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this question, which should answer yours:

[Convert a big integer to a full string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621792/convert-a-big-integer-to-a-full-string-in-php)

Comment: hmm-kay i'll give it a try.
however it doesn't seem that i have it activated on my local server...
do i have to download the library somewhere?
i don't see any vars in phpinfo()

EDIT: i got it http://gmplib.org/#DOWNLOAD thanks!