# PHP randomly decrements large integers by 1

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've stumbled across a weird bug/problem.

I have a MySQL table with a column filled with numbers (BIGINT). These numbers are too big for a regular 32 bit integer, so PHP will cast them to a string on 32-bit. This gives the correct result every time.

When run on 64 bit PHP and not forcibly cast to a string with `$variable = (string)$variable`, the result will *sometimes* be decremented by 1, such that a number like 1293203059233 becomes 1293203059232. This is no good obviously. The odd thing is that I cannot see any pattern.

It does not happen randomly such that one row from MySQL is decremented sometimes and sometimes not, but such that the same integers/rows are always decremented, and always by 1.

What could cause this? I use `json_encode` to convert `stdClass`-objects or `arrays()` to text, then send them by regular HTTP responses.

The rows are retrieved by `mysqli` using prepared statements such as :

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare->("SELECT BIGNUMBER FROM table WHERE SOMEID = ?");
$stmt->bind_result($bignumber);
$stmt->bind_param("i",$someid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->number = $bignumber;

echo json_encode($obj);
```

I have verified that all the integers are correct when browsing the database table.

Some examples (these are the actual values):

without cast to string:

```
10205160559939609 -> 10205160669939608 // bad
```

with:

```
10205160559939609 -> "10205160559939609" // good
```

without cast to string:

```
10154493437278508 -> 10154493437278508 // good (?)
```

with:

```
10154493437278508 -> "10154493437278508" // good
```

Edit: I did a error_log test pre-json_encode to test, yielding:

```
as Strng: (used error_log((string)$number);)
10205160559939609
as int: (used error_log($number);)
10205160559939609
```

Which would indicate that php does get the correct value, and that the error occurs in either php json_encode or in the browser's decode method.

Comment: Can you keep track of and list the numbers, see if anyone else can spot a pattern?

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622041/1866988

Comment: it's an exponential rounding error.

Comment: @Martin care to elaborate? If PHP can't correctly do math with such relatively small integers... then what

Comment: Possible duplicate except for the fact that these numbers are within PHPs regular 64 bit range, which is 9223372036854775807

Comment: @Martin `PHP_INT_MAX` for 64bit PHP is `9223372036854775807`, which is larger than `10205150669939609`.

Comment: My guess would be that it's related to the [known issue with json_encode and large integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589965/json-decode-and-json-encode-long-integers-without-loosing-data)... Can you reproduce it just with a specific integer and the json_encode?

Comment: Do you see any even/odd pattern?

Comment: @nickdnk Are you using PHP on Windows?

Comment: @MattGibson These numbers are also bigger than PHP_MAX_INT, it seems. At least in the question you linked.

Comment: No, it's Amazon EC2 default. 64 bit PHP.

Comment: With reference to @MattGibson 's link, does the same +/- 1 occur when the values are not `json_encoded`? Take them direct from the DB to the PHP output,

Comment: @nickdnk Does `json_encode([10205150669939609])` yield the correct value?

Comment: I will try that @Martin. Hold on.

Comment: @JoaquínO No pattern. The most pattern you get is from above examples.

Comment: Bear in mind this might be very specific to a PHP version/platform/architecture. There were quite a few bugs around big integers and json encoding, from what I recall.

Comment: @nickdnk Yeah, I just don't know what json_encode does with numbers. Bear in mind it's targeted for JavaScript, and in JavaScript, all numbers are actually floating point, as I understand it, even if they look like integers...

Comment: I can just cast them to string. The result is fine as a string in my case, fortunately. It just worries me that later down the line some of my maths will go wrong if I encounter a large integer at some point. Give me a minute and I'll have some results from the json_encode test.

Comment: @nickdnk Did you try my `json_encode([10205150669939609])`? (Just checking whether flat values work.)

Comment: Are you sure that it's an integer? Have you checked (`var_dump()`)? I can see how a float might do this kind of thing.

Comment: I guess I have an explanation for you.. `json_encode` turns your integers (17 digits) into floats.. Then, following php manual here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php you can see that there is some rounding error after a 16 digits precision.. Helps?

Comment: Simply typing in 10205150669939609 in the chrome console will give you the number 10205150669939608 printed out (rounding effect). I guess integers this big aren't valid in JS so neither should they be in JSON. I'd use strings if I had values that large.

Comment: @andrrs [JavaScript ≠ PHP](https://3v4l.org/CDHe5)

Comment: If you're going to be using these numbers in JavaScript, you definitely need to bear in mind that JavaScript numbers are *all* floating point. Even 3 is a floating point number in JavaScript. There will likely be precision errors the bigger the numbers get. [This issue](http://inessential.com/2014/04/13/vesper_sync_diary_13_unlucky_13) sprang to mind when I read your post.

Comment: @MattGibson That's just downright horrible news.

Comment: @nickdnk That's JavaScript :) But really, it all depends what these numbers really represent. If they're actually numbers, then do you need them to be so precise that 64-bit floating point has problems representing them? If they're not numbers, they should probably be strings.

Comment: @nickdnk Maybe I misinterpreted, but I just copied one of your numbers...

Comment: @andrrs Sorry, you did. I was too fast there. Maybe JavaScript is just useless with numbers this big.

Comment: In this case they represent facebook app scoped user ids, which are fine as strings. I was just wondering where this error came from. @MattGibson

Comment: Now I don't know how to answe this question.
As @andrrs pointed out, a simple console.log(10205150669939609) will give the wrong result, so this is entirely JavaScripts fault and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @nickdnk If I were you, I'd just answer it with the results you've found; it'll probably help the next person along who's running into this and can't quite figure out why...

Comment: True, but I wouldnt want to steal credit. @andrrs please post the answer

Comment: This should not be closed as duplicate, as the "answered duplicate" has nothing to do with this problem. It deals with integers bigger than PHP_INT_MAX, which this does not.

Comment: Indeed. This question isn't a duplicate as the problem is the representation of large (but below PHP_INT_MAX) numbers in JavaScript, not how PHP handles them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply typing in 10205150669939609 in the chrome console will give you the number 10205150669939608 printed out (rounding effect). I guess integers this big aren't valid in JS so neither should they be in JSON. I'd use strings if I had values that large.

Comment: from all the discussion in the comments I would hope that this answer would have been a bit , well, more educational.

Comment: such as clarifying that the issue is not with PHP itself, as the PHP_INT_MAX value is larger than the int used, and that the issue is specifically `JSON` encapsulation because javascript deems all numbers to be floating rather than integers. So it's a rounding error when a float (DOUBLE) is then brought back into being an INT type in PHP.

Comment: @Martin - "brought back into being an INT type in PHP.". Do you mean "in JavaScript"? PHP does not have any problems with my numbers.

Comment: @nickdnk PHP has no problems, but the numerical value is passed to JSON and stored in the JSON system and that is where the fault occurs and then when the number is passed back to the PHP (ie non-javascript) system then the fault is passed with it, due to JS using floats rather than INTs. :)

Comment: Also, @andrrs, please know that JSON is not type-aware. It will print any integer size correctly as integer, but JavaScript will fail to deserialize it.

Comment: https://cube-drone.com/comics/c/if-programming-languages-were-vehicles-iii